# cdk synth with stack name provided still synths all the stacks in the project

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

This is the app.py

```
my_env = cdk.Environment(account="XXXXXXX", region="us-east-1")
StackA(app, "stack-a", env=my_env)
StackB(app, "stack-b", env=my_env)
```

Each of these stacks has a print statement specifying the stack name. When I run this cli command `cdk synth StackA`, I get the lines below

```
Inside StackA 
Inside StackB
```

Why are both stacks sythesizing? How to ignore StackB when I only want StackA to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synth command synthesizes a CloudFormation template from your CDK code, and [per CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-synth), it will always run the whole app and generates the template in the `cdk.out` directory.

synth != deploy, synth will not apply any changes, it will only show the generated CloudFormation template.

When you try to do a synth, cdk will synthesize and generate templates for all of the stacks. Passing the stack name will show the template for only that stack. This behaviour can be verified by doing a `cdk synth` for a project that has multiple stacks

```
cdk synth
Successfully synthesized to cdk-cdn/cdk.out
Supply a stack id (all-images, images-cdn) to display its template.
```

Comment: The  documentation you linked shows synth with a stack name provided. So what is the purpose of providing a stack name to synth when it will synth everything in the end?

Comment: Providing the stack name will only print out the template for that specific stack

Comment: That command should have been `cdk synth show-template StackA`. That would have made more sense. The way the command is designed right now is misleading. Anyways thanks for your input.